# How to stop swiper slide autoplay on mouse enter and start autoplay on mouse leave?

Tags: swiper.js

How to stop swiper slide autoplay on mouse enter and start autoplay on mouse leave? I have tried .stopAutoPlay() and .startAutoPlay() function but not worked for me.

thank you here is code.

```
 var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
    paginationClickable: true,
    nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
    spaceBetween: 0,
    loop: true,
    effect: 'slide',
    longSwipes: true,
    autoplay:2000,
    autoplayDisableOnInteraction:true,
});


$(".swiper-container").mouseenter(function(){
    swiper.stopAutoPlay();
});

$(".swiper-container").mouseleave(function(){
    swiper.startAutoPlay();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check swiper API docs, u should use mySwiper.startAutoplay(), letter "p" is lowercase

Comment: Thank you ! Sergey Smekodub :)